# SQL: set field values based on single subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of values. let's say:

```sql
create table table1 (FirstName varchar(255), LastName varchar(255));

INSERT INTO table1 (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('Mariah1', 'Billy3');
INSERT INTO table1 (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('Mo2', 'Molly2');
INSERT INTO table1 (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('Sally3', 'Silly1');
```

I want to update all values to drop the numbers in names. so I tried:

```sql
UPDATE table1 t
SET (FirstName, LastName) = (
  select
  regexp_matches(FirstName ,'(\w+)\d+') as updatedFirstName,
  regexp_matches(LastName ,'(\w+)\d+') as updatedLastName
  FROM table1 u
  WHERE u.FirstName = t.FirstName and u.LastName = t.LastName
)
```

but then I get for instance:

`{Mariah}, {Billy}`

as values instead of:

`Mariah, Billy`

I tried adding `[0]` at the end, added extra `()` etc with no luck.

I'd like to know(with psql in mind ideally):

- If I can fix the above query by converting a subquery returning a single row, into a simple tuple. ie `('abc', 'def')`
- have an alternative way of doing the above update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use substring or regexp_replace:

substring extracts everything that is not a number:

```
update table1
   set firstname = substring(firstname from '[^0-9]+'),  
       lastname = substring(lastname from '[^0-9]+');
where firstname ~ '[0-9]'
   or lastname ~ '[0-9]';
```

or use regexp_replace to remove the numbers:

```
update table1
   set firstname = regexp_replace(firstname, '[0-9]+', '', 'g'),
       lastname = regexp_replace(lastname, '[0-9]+', '', 'g')
where firstname ~ '[0-9]'
   or lastname ~ '[0-9]';
```

The WHERE clause is used to avoid updating rows that don't need updating

Comment: ah briliant. using the original regex expression, which would involve extracting a pattern the replacements would look like: `regexp_replace(FirstName, '(\w+)\d+', '\1')`